# Unable to access FTP Server setup in AWS Windows machine through Internet

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall, ftp, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an AWS Windows Remote machine running Windows Server 2012, and I have set up an ftp server there with authenticated user, and I tired to access that FTP server in a browser in the same machine.

But I actually tried to access the same server in my laptop (outside of remote) and I wasn't able to access it. I tried in both FileZilla and browser and both didn't work. I checked the firewall and the FTP Inbound rule are enabled.

In FileZilla, I get 'Connection timeout, Could not connect to server' error message when I tried to access in port 21.

I don't know much about networking, but any idea what I am missing here? I want to access my FTP server via Internet? Will there be any restrictions from AWS (EC2 Instance) since I created a ftp server in an AWS Remote machine? Please advise.

Note: I did add Port 21 to Inbound and Outbound in Security Group tab in the portal.

Comment: Is this FTP or SFTP? *(if this is really FTP, it would be worthwhile to setup an SFTP or SCP server in AWS instead, as FTP should not be used anymore without using an encrypted tunnel)*

Comment: If I set up SFTP or SCP in my AWS Windows machine, can that be accessed through the internet? And do they not any encryption like FTP? Are you saying that the FTP server can not be accessed through internet without encryption tunnel? Please advise. @JonathanDavidArndt

Comment: How does your security group look like?

Comment: FTP and SFTP can (typically) be accessed the same way over the internet. (If you are using FileZilla, the only change you have to make is the port number, and FileZilla takes care of the rest). However, FTP has no encryption. Some internet services have begun to block unencrypted ports. It is worth trying SFTP or SCP to see if there is any difference.

Comment: You mean FileZilla Server in the remote machine or FileZilla Client in a machine via Internet? Where should I change the port number? In Firewall?

Comment: @Sam Do you have a Windows laptop?